# I have no experience with XML. How do i understand what is written in this XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have to start creating an android application. However, I have no experience with XML and understand the language. This XML file has data stored that I must use to create a Java program. I do not understand what I am looking at or how to read this language. I want to interpret the data so I can start coding it in Java. Please help.

I have tried to watch videos and learn XML but I cannot seem to apply the basics to interpret the information given to me in this file.

```
<task name="neddle decompression" steps="8">

    <step
        description="Obtain a 14 gauge needle with catheter
        from your first aid kit.">
        <aid aid="needle.jpg">
        </aid>
        <aid aid="needle.avi">
        </aid>
    </step>

    <step description="Locate position on chest.">
        <aid aid="position.jpg">
        </aid>
    </step>

    <step description="Prepare chest area with antiseptic.">
        <aid aid="none">
        </aid>
    </step>

    <step description="Insert the needle at a 90 degree angle.">
        <aid aid="insert.jpg">
        </aid>
    </step>

    <step
        description="Stop advancing the needle once a hiss of pop of air is heard. You should feel a 'pop' as the needle enters the chest cavity.">
        <aid aid="none">
        </aid>
    </step>

    <step description="Hold the catheter in place and remove the needle.">
        <aid aid="catheter.jpg">
        </aid>
    </step>

    <step description="Leave the catheter and safely dispose of the needle.">
        <aid aid="dispose.jpg">
        </aid>
    </step>

    <step
        description="Tape the catheter in place and monitor the casualty until the medivac is available to insert a chest tube.">
        <aid image="tape.jpg">
        </aid>
    </step>

</task>

<task name="task2" steps="2">

    <step description="step1">
        <aid image="image1.png">
        </aid>
    </step>

    <step destription="step2">
        <aid aid="image.png">
        </aid>
        <aid aid="image3.avi">
        </aid>
    </step>

</task>
```

I expect to get a guide of the classes and attributes I need to have in the Java program from this file.

Comment: Do you know how to process Json?

Comment: You must learn how to parse XML in java. https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: I don't think the XML you provided is specific to Android question.

Comment: What can we do if you say that you are unable to learn how to work with XML? I'd suggest you to hire online, or better - offline teacher for that. XML is way not the hardest thing in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great tutorial that is free in Udacity. It is also made by Google to help new android developers: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud834

Answer (score 1):

XML is just a format of your data, the content is inside open `tag` (Ex: `<person>`) and end `tag` (Ex: `</person>`). When your parent tag has child tags, just put these child tags between parent open tag and end tag and so on. Generally speaking, XML is a nested structure.

Simple example: A family (parent tag) has two members: Member 1 (level 1 child tag), Member 2 (level 1 child tag). Member 1 names Alice (level 2 child tag) and 24 year olds (level 2 child tag), Member 2 names Bob (level 2 child tag) and 27 year olds (level 2 child tag) then you have XML to store such data:

```
<family>
    <member>
        <name>Alice</name>
        <age>24</age>
    </member>
    <member>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>27</age>
    </member>
</family>
```

The easy way to parse XML format in Java is using DOM Parse, you can start with an simple example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm)

Good luck!